# Números perfectos y sus divisores C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

estoy realizando un programa en el cual se determinan cuales son los números perfectos que existen en un rango que el usuario especifica, cuando este introduce un rango limite el programa muestra los números perfectos comprendidos entre ese rango, mi problema es cuando quiero también imprimir juntamente con los números perfectos encontrados sus respectivos divisores para así comprobar que en realidad es un numero perfecto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace RangoPerfectos
    {
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int b; int s; int a; int num; int j;

        Console.Write("Determine hasta que numero desea realizar la busqueda de numeros perfectos: ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for(int i=1;i<=num;i++){
            b=0;
            s = i/2;

            for(j=1;j<=s;j++){

                a= i % j;

                if(a == 0)
                    b = b + j;
            }
            if(b== i)
                Console.WriteLine("El numero "+i+ " es perfecto y su divisores son: " +s);

        }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Por el momento solo he logrado que me imprima el ultimo divisor de cada numero perfecto, mas no todo el conjunto de divisores que conforman al numero perfecto y quiero imprimir no solo un divisor sino todos los divisores de cada numero perfecto encontrado.

Comment: Tenes un error de logica, y es pensar que la variable guarda mas de un valor. Una variable solo guarda el ultimo valor que le pasas. Deberias generar una matriz o una lista de valores y asi poder imprimirlos todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo de la siguiente forma, faltaba un acumulador:

```
    using System;

    namespace RangoPerfectos
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int b; int num; int j;
                string divisores = "";

                Console.Write("Determine hasta que numero desea realizar la busqueda de numeros perfectos: ");
                num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
                {
                    b = 0;

                    for (j = 1; j <= (i / 2); j++)
                    {
                        if (i % j == 0)
                        {
                            b += j;
                            divisores += " " + j + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    if (b == i)
                        Console.WriteLine("El numero " + i + " es perfecto y su divisores son: " + divisores);
                    divisores = "";
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero te sirva!